# Is it safe to only redirect non logged users on php?

Tags: php, html, security, session, logging

I'm creating a little website and i'm wondering since i had some lessons on http headers if it's safe to use such a logging algorithm :

```html
if(! isset($_SESSION["user"]) {

header("location : logout.php");

}

// and here i start my web page if the conditin above is not satisfied

<html> ........
```

i think it's not because the redirection can be ignored by a web client isn't it ?

Comment: it's unsafe only if you output more stuff that only authorized people should see. if the client ignores the redirect, and you output the protected content, they will be able to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its even better to add an 'else' statement just to prevent bugs from trolling you :)

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"]) {

    header("location : logout.php");
    exit("you are not authorized!");

} else { ?>
   <html>...</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

it is "safe" when you exit after the redirect - in case the redirect doesn't work:

```
if(! isset($_SESSION["user"]) {

    header("location : logout.php");
    exit("you are not authorized!");

}

// and here i start my web page if the conditin above is not satisfied

<html> ........
```